# Best way to convert ODBC DATE_STRUCT to a localized short format date string

Tags: c, windows

I found GetDateFormat, but that doesn't work with null dates (where I want 00:00:0000) as output.
Is there any localized, ie. using the 'Short date:' field of 'Regional Options' from the 'Regional and Language Options' Windows configuration dialog, API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetDateFormat`, `GetDateFormatEx`, `GetTimeFormat` or `GetTimeFormatEx` also `GetLocaleInfo` or `GetLocaleInfoEx`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319114.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318086.aspx